# rails 3 link_to image_tag --- Prevent the Addition of ?1290149059

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following tag:

```
<%= link_to image_tag @user.profile_pic.url(:medium) %>
```

Which generates:

```
<a href="/users/2"><img alt="Name" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/yadadadada/profile_pics/2/medium/yadadadada.jpeg?1290149059"></a>
```

How do I get rid of the ?1290149059

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you add a , false, paperclip will disable the timestamps.